# Email to Site Div

Tags: javascript, scripting, get, html-email

I have 8 emails being sent out and 1 webpage where they are linked to from the email.

If 1 email is about a particular subject I would like the link to go to the webpage and show a DIV on the subject out of the 8 choices.

I presume this is javascript and if so how, and are there any scripts out there I can use?

I hope this makes sense, but I'm happy to clarify. I think I need javascript to read the id GET variable

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 8 emails sent out that link to the same website?

Have the emails link to a URL with an ID appended as a GET variable:

```
Email 1 link: http://yousite.com/email.html?id=1
Email 2 link: http://yousite.com/email.html?id=2
Email 3 link: http://yousite.com/email.html?id=3
              ...
```

Then you can use server-side scripting or JavaScript to read the `id` GET variable.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. The URL does contain other variables so if some javascript on the site read the variable ?id=mobilephone for example, a div in the right hand column would show a laptop video. Any ideas on the javascript?

Comment: @Tim, if you have different contents each week as well as 8 different options, use both Greg's approach and anchors. The ID will let the system know the subject of the week and the anchor will let the system know what specific video is to be loaded. I'm supposing you want to "load" all the videos in the same page but switch the video you want to present at first, if that's not the case, please update the question.

Comment: Hi Yoda, yeah you're right.. all videos will be preloaded in the same page. Each weeks email will contain a different variable going to a specific video on that page. Can you help find a script that could do this? Thanks

Comment: Swapping out a DIV with a query string is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Despite @Greg's approach being usefull, I would use anchors for that matter, like :

```
http://yousite.com/email.html#option1
http://yousite.com/email.html#option2
http://yousite.com/email.html#option3
```

Comment: Can't really use anchors as that would mean 7 videos would be irrelevant. To clarify a bit more... I have 8 emails being sent out each week on a different subject and one site. Each week the subject will be different thus making the content on the site needing to be different. E.g. Week 1 is about mobile phones and if you click the link to the website a video on mobile phones will show in a DIV. Week 2 will be on Laptops so the link would need to go to the same site but the javascript would recognise the URL being slighty different and will show the Laptop video instead???

Comment: @Tim Using the hash is better because it's easier to read it in JavaScript. Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/HGhRG/ in your case have the `ParseHash()` function run at page load and it's a done deal. :)

Comment: I tried this and if there is an anchor used in the email link (from another HTML page) it doesn't work. It only works if you click the link you provided on the page itself.